# How to get Custom Attributes in Google Admin SDK API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We currently have custom fields in Google Admin for all of our company owned Chromebook devices. I am currently looking to GET our custom fields from Google Admin SDK API. I have researched through all of [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices?authuser=3) but I do not see anything referencing custom fields.

Can anyone provide me with documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this will help -- i struggled with the same thing. "projections/call options" are what you need:

```golang
// Projection and associated type/method implements CallOption
// interface to enable seeing custom user attributes.
//
// https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get#Projection
// https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/v0.14.0/googleapi/googleapi.go#L378
func Projection(p string) googleapi.CallOption {
        return projection(p)
}

// ...
func whatever() {
  // lists user with custom attributes
  u, _ := client.Users.Get(email).Do(Projection("FULL"))
  fmt.Printf("DEBUG: %+v", string(u.CustomSchemas["attribute_name"]))
}
```